# Rotation angle of a rectangle knowing only two diagonal vertices.

Tags: geometry

I'm wondering if there's a method to get the rotation angle of a rectangle in 2D space only knowing any of its two points that create a diagonal.

Essentially, having a rotated rectangle with vertices A,B,C,D and given coordinates of either A-C or B-D pair we are supposed to extract the rotation angle of the whole rectangle (against i.e the X axis).

It's easily doable for pairs of side coordinates (AB, CD etc.) so maybe there is a way for diagonals too?

[Diagram illustrating the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5P9o.png)

Answer (score 1):

A diagonal doesn’t determine a rectangle.

Consider the set of right triangles of which the hypotenuse is the interval $(-1, 1)$ on the $x$-axis. A famous result of geometry is that the locus of those triangles’ third vertices (the ones incident on their right angles) is the unit circle. Thus for any $0 < \theta < \pi$, there is a rectangle with vertices $(1,0)$, $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$, $(-1,0)$, $(-\cos \theta, -\sin\theta)$. And all these rectangles share that length-2 interval $(-1,1)$ as a diagonal.

You can confirm this by considering the vectors to the point $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ from the two endpoints, $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$, of the hypotenuse. Those vectors are $(\cos\theta-1,\sin\theta)^\bf T$ and $(\cos\theta+1,\sin\theta)^\bf T$, respectively. And their dot product is $\cos^2 \theta-1+\sin^2\theta = 0$, so they are perpendicular. Thus the angle incident on $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is indeed a right angle.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the side lengths of the rectangle you have (essentially) the same ambiguity for any rotation angle when you know just two vertices:

[image]